# Set a theoretical (not empirical) variogram in ArcGIS Geostatistical Analyst

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, geostatistical-analyst

I'm trying to do some Unconditional Gaussian Simulations using the Gaussian Geostatistical Simulation tool (see [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/How_Gaussian_Geostatistical_Simulations_works/00310000009r000000/)). However, I don't have any data that I am doing this from - just a theoretical parameterisation of a variogram model (lag, sill, nugget etc).

The Gaussian Geostatistical Simulation tool requires "an input geostatistical layer resulting from a Simple Kriging model". Is there a way to generate one of these without any data underlying it, and therefore purely from a theoretical variogram model? It seems that the Gaussian Geostatistical Simulation tool will only be using the variogram parameterisation, not the data, so it seems like it should be possible - I just can't see how!

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a random raster/point values from which you can calculate the sill, nugget and range -> This can technically be your random field, as in with a constant mean and homogeneous SD. Use those parameters from your random data and generate a surface through the tool.